# Is there such thing as an unlimited point matte in Premiere?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, keyframes

Basically my problem is I have footage which I need to manually key.  I need something like an unlimited point matte which would allow me to cut an actor out of a background by hand with no limits on the number of points in the matte.  Ideally this would be done in Premiere, but I have access to After Effects as well, I just don't like using it.  Also, if this is possible to do frame by frame as an image sequence in something like GIMP I can do that to.  I'm not sure if it's possible to import an alpha channel into Premiere though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the Rotobrush rotoscope tool in AE.. Good luck!  It will take a while...

Tutorial link:
https://library.creativecow.net/harrington_richard/after-effects-cs5-roto/1

Comment: Yeah, I knew no matter how efficient a tool I find, this is going to be pretty time consuming.  It's about 1800 frames.  I'll check that tool out though.

Comment: Mocha plugin for AE is also worth a look.  It's been used to roto a lot of feature films.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can use alpha masking in Premiere.  Basically you make a black and white animated layer that provides the opacity for the footage in Premiere and the effect gets applied to combine the two layers.  I will double check when I get home to make sure I'm not accidentally thinking of After Effects though.  I sometimes cross the two in my head since I switch between them pretty readily.

Comment: Think the advantage of the rotobrush is that it will try to predict where the edges are moving to, so in theory you don't have to re-adjust every frame, only correct it when it goes wrong. In practice though, it's not that clever...

Comment: You might also want to check out After Effect's mask tracking https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/rigid-mask-tracking.html